# What could be word for something which you can only partially remember? hardly recall/recollect?

Tags: single-word-requests

One example could be when you meet a person (Peter Parker)  and remember only that his name starts with P or may Par.

Comment: Duplicate question contains '...  I wasn't able to exactly recall 'Carl Sagan' but was in that situation where I could feel I almost remember it. I could recall there was the letter 'C' in his name.' in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of this could be a "hazy" or "vague" recollection. Assuming you're looking for a word that means to partially recall something.

"hazy":
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hazy

"vague":
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vague

Comment: This answer will be improved by including dictionary references for the suggested words.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Added. Thanks @KillingTime

Answer (score 3):

Well, let me offer you not a word but an idiom: **on the tip of (one's) tongue**

According to the [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+tip+of+my+tongue)

> 2. If something such as a word, answer, or name is **on the tip of your tongue**, you know it and can **almost remember**

You can **almost** remember Peter's surname but not fully complete.

As pointed by @nnnnn, notice that it *also applies when you can't remember any part of the word you're trying to think of, it's not specific to remembering part of the word.*

Comment: "I'll remember it the moment you say it..."

Comment: Apparently ["tip of the tongue phenomenon"](https://www.encyclopedia.com/psychology/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/tip-tongue-phenomenon) is the term used by a number of psychologists and researchers. See also [the relevant Straight Dope article](https://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1234/whats-the-word-for-when-you-cant-think-of-the-word/). (Of course TOT also applies when you can't remember any part of the word you're trying to think of, it's not specific to remembering part of the word.)

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right, it's not specific to just part of the word. I've included your statement

Answer (score 0):

In psychology/memory studies, this is called [interference](https://www.tutor2u.net/psychology/reference/proactive-and-retroactive-interference) or rather a specific type of interference called retroactive, this is when later learning (this can be any information) *hinders* previously discovered or “learnt” material:

> the tendency of later learning to hinder the memory of previously learned material.

Comment: This rather assumes that the lack of precision in memory is caused by interference and not, say, by simply forgetting.  I agree that interference may cause partial memory loss, but not that it is the only potential cause.

Answer (score 0):

**Glimmering** 'could' be the word you are reaching for.  In other words, just a glimpse of the word you really want.